# Can we deploy multiple camel muliple version 2.10 and 2.12.4 on Jboss Fuse 6.0

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

We are developing a camel route to be deployed on JBoss Fuse 6.
There are existing camel routes already deployed which are on version 2.10. But my camel application in on version 2.12.4 can both the version of the application reside on same fuse server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to have two different versions of a project in the same container as you may end up in a dependency mess. That said, you can have two different versions of Camel, just make sure your manifest and osgi import sections uses the correct versions of the libraries.